# How to know if we are in the Parent PreferenceScreen or in a nested one

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've a settings.xml file like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="GeneralScreen"
        android:title="@string/generalParameters" >
        <EditTextPreference
            android:dialogTitle="@string/companyName"
            android:key="CompanyName"
            android:title="@string/companyName" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:dialogTitle="@string/companyAddress"
            android:key="CompanyAddress"
            android:title="@string/companyAddress" />
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I've a PreferenceFragment :

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceFragment {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
....
```

I need a method which returns if 1) I'm in the parent PreferenceScreen 2) if I'm a nested PreferenceScreen (or even a multiple nested)

Do you know a method to find that information ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling in your `PreferenceActivity`

`if(getPreferenceScreen() != null)`

or

`if(getPreferenceScreen().getTitle()!=null)`.

If the condition is **true** - you are in a `PreferenceScreen`.

Aware that **This method was deprecated in API level 11.
This function is not relevant for a modern fragment-based PreferenceActivity.**